# JQuery animate calculate pixel distance

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using JQuery to animate a panel system menu. The problem is that there are 5 panels and I cannot set the panel left: attribute directly as it needs to calculate it based on its current position. My script should explain.

```
$('.panel').animate({left: '-250'}, 300);
```

So this is fine as on the first click it slides the first panel out of the view and the second panel into view. On a click in the second panel however it will not slide to the third panel as it is telling all the panels .panel to move to `left:-250`. I want it to work out what the current left:?? is of .panel and then add a further `-250` to animate.

That way if `left:0` we are on the first panel and on a click we will go to `left:-250`. On click on the second panel it will add `-250 + -250` and animate to `-500` etc.. etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: The alternative is to use the operator: -= or += _as per the demo_ on the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) page [which can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8WyW/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the position using offset or offset parent.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

http://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/

Something like this; (not tested)

```
    var offset = $('.panel').offset();
    alert(offset.left);
    alert(offset.top)
    var newpos = [offset.left - 250]
    $('.panel').animate({left: newpos}, 300);
```